# No Element Found error C# and firefox driver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

What I am trying to do is to click on a linked text which is "abcdqa83814".

I tried linked text and partial linked text but I am getting "no element found error".

This is where the script is failing:

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("abcdqa83814")).Click();
```

and the HTML is:

```
<a tabindex="6" href="http://stgsupport.abcd.com/CustomerService/LoadCustomerFields?contactId=0037011111FPM3gAAH" 
    class="Aec400cdd43c349109363b9fb04c1126032a" 
    target="_top">abcdqa83814</a>
```

It's not a timeout issue as I debugged it and made sure the page is loaded completely.

Please let me know if any one has the same issue and how I could fix it.

Comment: Can you provide the correct html part within and including the <a> and </a> tags?

Comment: Provide complete HTML if possible. There is a chance that this could be inside a frame.

Comment: can you  please let me know  how to use href value for  xpath.The html tag with <a

Comment: its iframe  issue. Thank you  i could able to solve it